# Find IP address of poe devices attached to my computer via ethernet

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, nmap, ip-address

I'm currently trying to setup zoneminder on my computer that has Ubuntu as a host OS.

Before I do all that, I want to know if the poe CCTV camera I purchased works, a Reolink RLC410-5MP

There are multiple ways to achieve this but the simplest one I found was to use the rstp URL in VLC
After searching the correct format for the URL, this is what I found

> Main Stream: rtsp://admin:password@ip_address:554//h264Preview_01_main

What I need now is the IP address of the CCTV, which is connected directly to my laptop via an Ethernet cable and is being powered by a power supply

I'm not 100% sure how to find the IP address, one way I found is using

```
nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24
```

However the above shows 8 devices connected and I'm puzzled as I should be only expecting one/two devices(the CCTV and maybe the router?)

What's the best way to find the IP address of a poe device physically attached to a laptop via an ethernet cable?

Comment: Does the device get IP via DHCP? If so, simply check the DHCP servers lease file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean via the DHCP, how do I check this?

Comment: How does the device get a IP? Does it have a standard IP? Does it use DHCP to acquire the IP? Did it have a previously set IP address? Does it fall back [APIPA](https://wiki.wireshark.org/APIPA) if there's no DHCP?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with this process, all I know that POE devices get an IP address autoatically, I used this guide that is for windows but gives some info on how poe devices works, https://reolink.com/connect-security-ip-camera-to-pc/
I looked a method 1

Comment: No, there's no mechanism in Power Over Ethernet for assigning IP addresses. Network devices commonly use DHCP to automatically get IP's. Unless DHCP is used, the process will differ from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Comment: Also, based on my understanding of what I read I believe it doesn't have a standard IP, one gets assigned to it. In method one it talks about changing it to static as otherwise it will change once you reboot the device

Comment: The mechanism for assigning IP's is commonly DHCP. But if you don't have a DHCP server running on your laptop, and it's only connected to your laptop, that is obviously not used. Commonly your home router acts as DHCP server for devices *attached to it*.

Comment: How do I check if a DHCP server is running on my laptop? I was hoping the method 1 in the link I posted earlier will help but that doesn't mention having any DHCP server running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94394/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-sgr).

Comment: Welcome, create a new wired connection (Method : shared to others...) . An ip address should be assigned to your device.

Comment: Its connected "directly" to your laptop but using the same address space as your LAN? I think you need to review your question.

Comment: Some of your writing in ambiguos. You say *" find the IP address of a poe device physically attached to a laptop via an ethernet cable"*, but just above that you speculate *"I should be only expecting one/two devices(the CCTV and maybe the router?"* with **maybe the router** being the ambiguity in your problem descrription. The router (should) provide DHCP for anything connected to it. This would be the typical map ... `laptop<->router(DHCP)<->IP camera`, right? Please clarify your question NOT IN THE COMMENTS please (-;! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For the situation where you attach an unknown device directly to your computer (laptop), the first thing to try is to run a DHCP server on your computer and *give* it an address.

The you look at the log of the DHCP server and you'll know which address it has.

The DHCP protocol works very roughly like this: A device broadcasts a "hello, I'm new in this subnet! Can anyone give me an IP address?" message, and the DHCP server answers "welcome, new device, here is your IP address in this subnet, and other network information you may find useful".

Details how to run and configure a DHCP server depend on your distro. I am using Debian, running the `isc-dhcp-server` package, which is configured in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` and logs to syslog.

The fun starts if the unknown device is not using DHCP, but instead gives itself a static IP address. Then you read the manual, or indeed you run `nmap`, interprete the answer(s) and try more things to find out what the device does in detail.

Comment: As an alternative, if the hosts are on the same link, you can use mDNS or LLNMR (Link-local Multicast Name Resolution). These mechanisms work roughly like this: the client sends a multicast message "I want to talk to host A", host A responds "That's me, here is my IP address".

Comment: @JohanMyréen Though if a decice supports mDNS, it will likely also do a DHCP request, while on the other hand there are devices that do only DHCP requests (it's the simpler protocol), and don't offer mDNS. So I'd try DHCP first.

Comment: On the other hand, mDNS also works with autoconfigured addresses, and link-local (IPv6) addresses.